# polymer test on gitlab CI

Tags: polymer, gitlab, polymer-1.0, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I've got a problem running polymer test on gitlab CI shared runner. I got stuck in `Selenium error: no such session` when running chromedriver. It didn't appear on running firefox. How can I run polymer test in gitlab CI using xvfb-run -a polymer test to run in chrome browser?

This is my .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
image: node:6.9.5
before_script:
  - wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
  - echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
  - echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list
  - echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list
  - apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys EEA14886
  - echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections
  - apt-get update -yqqq
  - apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer
  - apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
  - apt-get install -y iceweasel
  - apt-get install -y xvfb
  - npm install -g bower
  - npm install -g polymer-cli
  - bower install --allow-root
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - deploy
testing:
  stage: test
  script:
    - xvfb-run -a polymer test
  only:
    - develop
  tags:
    - docker
```

This is the error report:
http://pastebin.com/wsVMLc83

Thank you.